# reload image using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, image-upload

I'm uploading an image using ajax.

i want to make this function to work with class name instead of ids.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var button = $('#uploader'), interval;

new AjaxUpload(button, {
    action: 'upload.php',
    onSubmit : function(file , ext){
    if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
        alert('Error: Only images are allowed');
        return false;
    } else {
                  // Image Accepted.
    }
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
        button.attr("src", response);
    }   
});



});
```

in html

```
<img id="uploader" src="" />
```

works fine but i want to add more img tags.

please suggest how can i change this function to work with class instead of ids

```
<img class="uploader" src="" />
<img class="uploader" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about jQuery class seletor [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).
I guess you would then use jQuery `.each` to loop all buttons or what not.

Comment: img tags are being create dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var button = $('.uploader'), interval;
```

And:

```
<img class="uploader" src="" />
<img class="uploader" src="" />
```

Comment: if possible, i would like to make this as a function and i will call it by passing classname.